# Is there any way to change Scala's _root_ namespace "keyword"?

Tags: scala

As for me `_root_` keyword looks awkward. It looks like Python style or hack.

```
_root_.launch.Booster3
```

I wonder can it be changed by language architects to something like this

```
_.launch.Booster3
```

Or may be like C# style using global::

```
global::launch.Booster3
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx

or

```
root.launch.Booster3
```

where "root" will be treated as keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_` is a bad choice because it's something of a "whatever fits" placeholder, while `_root_` is anything *but* whatever fits.

`root` is a bad choice because people have already presumably used `root`--adding new keywords is likely to be highly disruptive.  Since `_` are discouraged in names of all kinds, picking an identifier with `_` to have a special meaning is one of the safest things one can do.

`global::` is a bad choice because `global` and `::` are each independent identifiers which are not reserved key words.  It looks like you're trying to prepend the global item onto a list containing the rest of the package name.  In Scala, `::` is list concatenation (cons); it is far more jarring to find it in a namespace than it is to find a perfectly valid if slightly unusual identifier like `_root_`.

I agree `_root_` looks awkward (though note that it should only come up in awkward cases where your package hierarchies have name conflicts).  But there are good reasons for something like this, and now that it's been done it would take a very, very compelling reason to change it.

Comment: But what about C# way: global::launch.Booster3?

Comment: @serg.f - Added a paragraph about `global::`.

Comment: May be global: (single colon) or root: ?

Comment: @serg.f - Then it's specifying a type.